# Apostrophecms: TypeError: req.__ns is not a function

Tags: apostrophe-cms

after upgrading to v2.105.0 I'm getting this error all the time.

`TypeError: req.__ns is not a function
    at Object.self.getCreateSingletonOptions (/../node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/lib/browser.js:26:23)
    at Object.self.pushCreateSingleton (/../node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-module/index.js:637:26)
    at Object.self.pageBeforeSend (/../node_modules/apostrophe/lib/modules/apostrophe-areas/lib/browser.js:18:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/../node_modules/apostrophe/index.js:598:20)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)`

downgrading to 2.104.0 helps, but is there is a way to solve it?

Comment: I'd suggest submitting something like this as a bug report rather than a SO question. It's not really something to solve in your code. https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/new/choose

Comment: To build on Bea's comment, we would really like to help with this but we haven't seen anything like it, so we need to know how the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are overriding the apostrophe-express module, you need to update your lib/modules/apostrophe-express/index.js. Comparing to the current version, it seems you need to add the following line at 413:

```
self.apos.app.use(self.apos.modules['apostrophe-i18n'].namespacesMiddleware);
```

Assuming that line 412 is this:
`self.apos.app.use(self.apos.i18n.init);`

Well, at least this fixed the exact same error for me.